# Template based code generation that tracks/merges user changes?

Tags: c#, code-generation

Does a template/code generator already exist that tracks user changes to it's output? I'm not even posative this makes sense - but the space cadet in me thinks something like this could be an interesting kind of change tracking that integrates more tightly to the code than SCM...

Data.xml

```
<Classes>
 <Class>Class1</Class>
</Classes>
```

Template

```
<# for(var c in XDocument.Load("Data.xml").Element("Classes").Elements("Class")) { #>
     class <#=c.Value#> {
       public <#=c.Value#>() {
         // <InsertPoint>
         // </InsertPoint>
       }
     }
<# } #>
```

Output

```
class Class1 {
  public Class1() {
    // <InsertPoint>
    // </InsertPoint>
  }
}
```

User Change

```
class Class1 {
  public Class1() {
    // <InsertPoint>
    System.Console.WriteLine("I am Class1");
    // </InsertPoint>
  }
}
```

--> The template changes to something like:

```
<# for(var c in XDocument.Load("Data.xml").Element("Classes").Elements("Class")) { #>
class <#=c.Value#> {
  public <#=c.Value#>() {
  // <UserInsert id="1">
  System.Console.WriteLine("I am Class1");
  // </UserInsert>

  // <InsertPoint>
  // </InsertPoint>
  }
}
<# } #>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in data.xml is what's normally called a model. Being done in XML, we could call this a "tree model". In other words, you are applying (executing) templates according to a pre-defined model.

Tracking user changes in this case can also be called "round-trip" engineering: a bi-directional change.

The [ABSE](http://www.abse.info) project (disclaimer: I am the project lead) defines a model-driven code generation approach that is very close to your request: It uses executable templates and generates code by means of a tree model (but it's not XML). But instead of detecting your changes in code, you can add your own code directly in the model so that you can skip the "round-trip" step.

Comment: looks interesting but i don't see how to download it (or is it not possible?)

Comment: ABSE is just the development approach. There is an IDE that implements ABSE called AtomWeaver, at http://www.atomweaver.com

Answer (score 0):

There are tools for diff'ing on xml documents. If you can convert your code into an ast, represented in xml, you could apply these tools on the document, then transform it back to code.

Comment: do you know one off hand? (of course i can google, just seeing if you already did for me :) )

Comment: I don't know any good enough to recommend. I would suggest you pick one from a google search.